# JButton will not resize using BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm making a small calendar app to refamiliarize myself with Java Swing, and I'm trying to use a `BoxLayout` to display the events I've added in order. I've got the events displaying one on top of the other, but I can't resize them.

I have an `ArrayList` of JButtons called `events` and the size of the window is 400x400px. I have this code:

*Edit: Updated the code below to be a proper example.*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DateDisplay extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DateDisplay();
    }
    
    public DateDisplay() {
        File file = new File("2.23.2023.txt");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        ArrayList<JButton> events = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        
        if(file.exists()) {
            Scanner reader;
            try {
                reader = new Scanner(file);
                while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("in");
                    events.add(new JButton(reader.nextLine()));
                    panel.add(events.get(events.size()-1));
                    reader.nextLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        for(JButton btn : events) {
            btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 40));
            panel.add(btn);
        }
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(panel);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, `BoxLayout` should still honor `setMinimumSize()`, but it doesn't seem to be.

Buttons only being the minimum size to hold the text:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpQVJ.png]

*Edit: This is the text of the file I've been using for testing purposes.*

```
Laundry - 16:00

Groceries - 17:00
```

If the `BoxLayout` was still honoring `setMinimumSize()`, would these buttons not be the width of the frame, or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @camickr Thanks! I hadn't realized that was how minimum size worked. The GridLayout worked much better.

Comment: _GridLayout worked much better_ each layoutManager has its own specific behavior, please study the api doc to learn how they re/size their children

Comment: .. also have look at the good ol' oracle layout tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Comment: you already know that you have to change the buttons' max (__not__ the min) to unbounded .. what's left as the problem? btw: good to add an example - but .. reading a file to get data is not quite minimal - simply hard-code some values :)

Comment: .. or maybe I don't quite understand the requirement (did it change during the edit?) - you might want to explain the _exact_ behavior you want to achieve, both initial and when resizing the window.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the advice. the requirement stayed the same, maybe I changed exactly how I implemented it when I edited my post, I'm not sure. I've found that I can either stick with BoxLayout and set the maximum size, or use GridLayout and just use the size it gives me